# Can QGIS render and show DTM (Digital Terrain Model)?

Tags: qgis, dem

I wonder if qgis can properly render a DTM (triangle) layer (as shown in image1) and become like a moveable (orbit-able) map to export to web browser?

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

If this is possible, where should I start from?

Currently the output of DTM layer looks so 2D and flat.. Did I import it with a wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at QGIS2threejs. It allows you to export a terrain model to a web viewer. it's available as a plugin, just search for it in the plugins dialog.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Qgis2threejs/

There are settings for draping a DTM with an ortophoto, as well as extruding polygons and so on.

Not sure if it works out of the box with a mesh geometry, but I think  it's a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you hexamon! This is helpful.

Comment: But after I export this 3D viewer to web browser, it only works on local directory properly. That is, if I host it, the 3D viewer takes ages to load and show up..

Comment: I was using firebase free hosting server. Will that be the reason of extremely slow loading? If I go with a proper hosting solution, will this performance be enhanced? :)

Comment: @AndyYang Not sure. I don't have experience with FireBase. But I think the rendering is done client side, so the performance of the map should only be impacted by the connection in terms of loading the data. Once the data is loaded there should be no difference between running it locally and remote. I'm not 100 % sure about this though, but consider it a qualified guess...

Comment: Check the file size of the exported viewer. How big is it?

Comment: I am not sure as well.it only render locally within 30 seconds thou. For the hosted online version, it took me forever to load and never showed up lol...  (The entire folder size is 128MB which is quite big aye :)

Comment: Strange. I found this QGIS2threejs project someone else hosted on FireBase: https://gvlt-72b23.firebaseapp.com/qgis3js/montmartre.html . Here is the blogpost: https://gvlt.wordpress.com/2014/11/19/paris-in-3d-with-qgis-and-three-js/ . Maybe your model is a bit too detailed? Perhaps try to do some generalisations via the processing toolbox before export.

Comment: You are the man!! the blog and his render on firebase is smooth and breathtaking!!!  I will do some research and let you know how it goes :) Cheers bro